# HtmlPanelGroup - binding - h:panelGroup tree depth

Tags: jsf, binding, components, facelets

I am facing the issue a few times but seem like I am not sure how to solve this... If I use `HtmlPanelGroup` as :

**client :**

```
<h:panelGroup ... binding="#{myBean.myPanelGroup}">
</h:panelGroup>
```

**backing bean(s) :**

```
@ManagedBean(name="myPanelGroup")
@RequestScoped
public class G0 extends HtmlPanelGroup{
  ...
  public void addComp(ActionEvent e){
   HtmlCommandButton commandButton=new HtmlCommandButton();
   commandButton.setValue("aValue");

   G1 g1=new G1();
   g1.addComp(commandButton);

   this.getChildren().add(g1);
}
}
```

**another object :**

```
@FacesComponent(value="myPanel")
public class G1 extends HtmlPanelGroup{
  ...
  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){this.setLayout("block");}
  public void addComp(UIComponent c){this.getChildren().add(c);}//bare button only :(
}
```

for some reason the generated HTML contains **bare** command button which is not surrounded by G1 (the div) at all :P

p.s the taglib.xml does contains the G1 configuration as :

```
...
    <tag>
    <tag-name>aTag</tag-name>
    <component>
      <component-type>myPanel<component-type>
    </component>
    </tag>
...
```

**EDIT**

Or `h:panelGroup`-s tree like this may cause a similar issue :

**client side :**

```
<h:panelGroup ... binding="#{gBean.g}"/>
```

**backing bean :**

```
    public class G extends HtmlPanelGroup{
    ...
    HtmlPanelGroup g0;
    HtmlPanelGroup g1;
    HtmlPanelGroup g2;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       g0=new HtmlPanelGroup();
       g0.setStyleClass("g0");
       g1=new HtmlPanelGroup();
       g1.setStyleClass("g1");
       g2=new HtmlPanelGroup();
       g2.setStyleClass("g2");

       g0.getChildren().add(g1);
       g1.getChildren().add(g2);
       this.getChildren().add(g0);
    }
    ...
    }
```

**and the bean :**

```
    @ManagedBean(name="gBean")
    @RequestScoped
    public class GBean {
      ...
      private G g;
      ...
      @PostConstruct
      public void initGBean(){
      g=new G(); 
    }

    public void addComp(ActionEvent e){
      HtmlCommandButton c=new HtmlCommandButton();
      c.setValue(""+Math.random());

      this.g.getChildren().add(c);
}
     //getters setters
    }
```

So my question is... 
What causes that and how to fix that or is there a workaround?

And I am still not sure is there a limit about the div's (`h:panelGroup`) tree depth in frames of JSF? If not how to work it around cause it is quite annoying; Or is there a more alternative way?

Thanks

Comment: I am really stuck with it :S Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `@PostConstruct` doesn't work in case it is not `@ManagedBean` *(correct me if I am wrong)*; In case of an object which extends `HtmlPanelGroup` (see code snippet) :

```
public class G extends HtmlPanelGroup{
    ...
    HtmlPanelGroup g0;
    HtmlPanelGroup g1;
    HtmlPanelGroup g2;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       g0=new HtmlPanelGroup();
       g0.setStyleClass("g0");
       g1=new HtmlPanelGroup();
       g1.setStyleClass("g1");
       g2=new HtmlPanelGroup();
       g2.setStyleClass("g2");

       g0.getChildren().add(g1);
       g1.getChildren().add(g2);
       this.getChildren().add(g0);
    }
    ...
    }
```

so to have the method invok-ed I decided to use constructor as (see code snippet)

```
public class G extends HtmlPanelGroup{
    ...
    HtmlPanelGroup g0;
    HtmlPanelGroup g1;
    HtmlPanelGroup g2;


   public G(){
     this.init();
   }

    public void init(){
       g0=new HtmlPanelGroup();
       g0.setStyleClass("g0");
       g1=new HtmlPanelGroup();
       g1.setStyleClass("g1");
       g2=new HtmlPanelGroup();
       g2.setStyleClass("g2");

       g0.getChildren().add(g1);
       g1.getChildren().add(g2);
       this.getChildren().add(g0);
    }
    ...
    }
```

...in case of jsf so called **backing bean** it is fine to use a some kind of common POJO way;

---

p.s. I am still working this around so feel free to comment the tips :)

Cheers